# Fitting a truncated normal to data

Tags: maximum-likelihood, truncated-normal-distribution

I consider the normal distribution truncated to the half-interval $[0,\infty)$,

$$
P(x) = \sqrt{ \frac{2}{\pi\sigma^{2}} } \frac{1}{\operatorname{erfc}\left( -\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{ 2\sigma^{2} }} \right)} \exp\left( -\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}} \right)
$$

for $x\geq0$, while $P(x)=0$ for $x<0$.

Given some observations $x_{1},\dots,x_{M}$, I want to maximize the log-likelihood:

$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{n=1}^{M}\ln P(x_{n}) = \frac{1}{2}\ln\left( \frac{2}{\pi} \right) - \ln(\sigma) - \ln\operatorname{erfcx}\left( -\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{ 2\sigma^{2} }} \right) + \frac{2\mu S_{1}-S_{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}
$$

with respect to the parameters $\mu,\sigma$, and where it is assumed that $x_{n}\geq0$ for all $n$. Here we introduced the sufficient statistics:

$$
S_{1}=\frac{1}{M}\sum_{n}x_{n},\quad
S_{2}=\frac{1}{M}\sum_{n}x_{n}^{2}
$$

Note that the truncation interval $[0,\infty)$ is fixed (i.e., it is not inferred).

Now it seems that maximizing $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to $\mu,\sigma$ is a bit tricky. Here is what I tried. Differentiating,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{ \partial \mathcal{L} }{ \partial \mu } &= -\frac{1}{\sigma}\left( \Psi\left( \frac{\mu}{\sigma} \right) - \frac{S_{1}}{\sigma} \right) \\
\frac{ \partial \mathcal{L} }{ \partial \sigma } &= \frac{\mu}{\sigma^{2}}\Psi\left( \frac{\mu}{\sigma} \right) - \frac{1}{\sigma} + \frac{S_{2}-2S_{1}\mu}{\sigma^{3}} \\
\end{align}$$

where

$$\Psi(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{ 2\pi }} \frac{1}{\operatorname{erfcx}\left( -\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right)} + x$$

and

$$\operatorname{erfcx}(x) = \exp(x^{2})\operatorname{erfc}(x)$$

Setting the gradient equal to zero, we get that:

$$\Psi\left( \frac{\mu}{\sigma} \right) = \frac{S_{1}}{\sigma},\quad
S_{2} - S_{1}\mu = \sigma^{2}$$

I tried solving these equations by iteration, but often they do not converge. I need to optimize $\mathcal{L}$ inside nested loop as part of fitting a large model, so the optimization should be as fast as possible. Any suggestions on how to tackle this? I also tried Newton but I also get convergence problems.

Comment: Possibly consider the problem as a missing data problem. with a sample of unknown size $N$ from the standard Gaussian $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ has been cut from its negative values. I did not check the details but an EM algorithm could potentially apply to this setting.

Comment: Update: I tried but it does not help for the EM version...

Comment: If you replace $\mu/\sigma$ with $\alpha$, you can get the maximum likelihood estimate of $\sigma$ in terms of $\alpha$ (at least narrowed down to just two different values of $\hat\sigma$).  That makes it a one-dimensional problem and likely fewer convergence issues.

Comment: @JimB Yes, that's a good idea. Though the one-dimensional system I get is still tricky.